# Why alt-tab stays behind Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, alt-tab

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Windows 7 alt-tab window disappears to back when aero peek is enabled](https://superuser.com/questions/183605/windows-7-alt-tab-window-disappears-to-back-when-aero-peek-is-enabled)

I have a very annoying problem that appears randomly. Sometimes it works fine sometimes it doesn't. The problem is that the centered thumbnails that appears when <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>tab</kbd> is pressed stays behind the window preview, so any subsequent press to <kbd>tab</kbd> it shows the full screen preview but the thumbnails remains *behind it*.

In essence, the z-order of the mini-previews is not the top-most. Any hint or way to fix it?

Comment: Are you on the latest service pack (SP1) and all the available updates from Microsoft?

Comment: I have precisely this problem, and I have SP1 and all updates. It has been like this for quite some time, actually.

Answer (score 0):

Don't exactly know what causes it, but here's a workaround: Use <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd>.